# CMake set variables before defined, access them after being defined

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to set a bunch of variables before they are defined e.g., when using CUDA and I write

```
SET(MY_CUDA_LIBS CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES CUDA_CUFFT_LIBRARIES),
```

such that when are being defined by

```
FIND_PACKAGE(CUDA REQUIRED)
```

(`CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES` and `CUDA_CUFFT_LIBRARIES` can now be accessed i.e., `${CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES}` and `${CUDA_CUFFT_LIBRARIES}` are the paths to the corresponding library), I can access something like `${MY_CUDA_LIBS}` and it returns `${CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_CUFFT_LIBRARIES}`?

This obviously works, if I e.g. use `CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES` only and do `${${MY_CUDA_LIBS}}`, but as soon as one has multiple libraries this trick does not work anymore and it returns CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIESCUDA_CUFFT_LIBRARIES or "nothing".

The idea is to define the CUDA libraries in the very beginning of my `CMakeLists.txt` and it (far) later automatically inserts the corresponding path when accessed in `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you should treat the `MY_CUDA_LIBS` as a list. Then, the following is possible:

```
set(MANY_LIBS LIB_1 LIB_2)
set(LIB_1 "/libs/lib1")
set(LIB_2 "/libs/lib2")
list(GET MANY_LIBS 0 PATH)
message(${${PATH}})
list(GET MANY_LIBS 1 PATH)
message(${${PATH}})
```

resulting in the following output as predicted:

```
/libs/lib1
/libs/lib2
```

If you want it to use later in `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` you probably can do the following after your variable are defined properly:

```
foreach(libname ${MANY_LIBS})
    list(APPEND MANY_LIBS_PATHS ${${libname}})
endforeach(${MANY_LIBS_PATHS})
message("${MANY_LIBS_PATHS}")
```

after that, `MANY_LIBS_PATHS` can be used for linking.

Comment: Wow so cool. Just one thing. Now `${MANY_LIBS_PATHS}` returns `/libs/lib1/libs/lib2`, but it should be `/libs/lib1 /libs/lib2`, if I'm not mistaken?!

Comment: @SemtexB, it is just the output of `message`. I added the quote marks for `message` to output the value correctly. The values in `MANY_LIBS_PATHS` were correct anyway.